# Docs for antd nuxtjs when using babel-plugin-import

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, nuxt.js, antd

I am setting up the first app using Nuxtjs and Antd. I am using `babel-plugin-import` to reduce bundle size of Antd.

It works fine but in the component, it seem strange.

with `babel-plugin-import`

```
<template>
  <Button type="primary">Enjoy it</Button>
</template>

<script>
import { Button } from 'ant-design-vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Button
  }
}
</script>
```

On the official docs, they are using different tags.

`<a-button type="primary">Primary</a-button>`

This is the [docs](https://www.antdv.com/components/button/) from Ant Design of Vue.

How can I find the docs when using with `babel-plugin-import`. I already search many times on the internet. But I am not finding any results.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

```
<script>
import Button from 'ant-design-vue/lib/button';

export default {
  components: {
    'a-button':Button
  }
}
</script>
```

In this thread: [Import UI library modularized in nuxtjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53146692/9246918)

Answer (score 0):

#### the elegant way:

```
components: {
    [Button.name]: Button
}
```